# Get timzone compared to GMT in Android

Tags: java, android, timezone, integer

I need to get the mobile **TimeZone** comparing to **GMT** in Android. I only could see one function returns that but as `String`:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
TimeZone tz = c.getTimeZone();
tz.getID();
```

This is the description of `getID()`:

> Returns the ID of this TimeZone, such as America/Los_Angeles, GMT-08:00 or UTC.

The problem is I need to get that as `Integer` like +3, -5...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to calculate the difference based on the TimeZone `getOffset()` value, see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset(long)

Comment: +1 for efforts, just one last thing to accept the answer: does this number of hours comes with minus if the timezone is GMT -3 it will come -10800000?

Comment: Yeah it should just be a negative value of the same magnitude. To verify this you could test it with a TimeZone like PST or EST.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static String getCurrentTimezoneOffset() {

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();  
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz);
    int offsetInMillis = tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    String offset = String.format("%02d:%02d", Math.abs(offsetInMillis / 3600000), Math.abs((offsetInMillis / 60000) % 60));
    offset = (offsetInMillis >= 0 ? "+" : "-") + offset;

    return offset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [TimeZone.getOffset](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset%28long%29). Be aware that the time difference can change due to daylight saving time and that can widely vary per country and day of year. You should therefore not rely on that offset number throughout the year. Instead it is more reliable to use the TimeZone identifier instead.

Comment: So you are suggesting to create a method to read the string of the TimeZone identifier and somehow get the offset as Integer from it using String and Integer operations?

Comment: No, not quite... I just wanted to give you a word of advice alongside my answer to your question. Sorry for that misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, now I used getOffset, but I don't understand how to use its value? it gave me 1080000, my time is GMT+3, how can I translate that big number?

Comment: The offset is in milliseconds. Divide by 1000*60*60 to get the number of hours.

Comment: The documentation for `TimeZone.getOffset` indicates that it will take daylight saving time into account. So it should be giving you the correct offset for the specific given time.